# Matplotlib output line chart looks "box like" (for lack of a better word) for monthly data sampled over a 30 year period

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, formatting, linechart

I am doing a very simple chart with Matplotlib and Python. It is 30 years worth of monthly sampled data (PMI - US Purchasing Manager Index). All up it has around 400 monthly observation.

Sample monthly data:

| Date | PMI |
| --- | --- |
| 1/03/2022 | 57.1 |
| 1/02/2022 | 58.6 |
| 1/01/2022 | 57.6 |
| 1/12/2021 | 58.8 |
| 1/11/2021 | 60.6 |
| 1/10/2021 | 60.8 |
| 1/09/2021 | 60.5 |

I produced a very simple line chart with Matplotlib. Dataframe name is pmi. Date is not set to index but dates are set to pandas.datetime.

`plt.plot(pmi.Date, pmi.PMI, c='mediumblue', lw=0.8)`

Output:

[image: chart of monthly PMI data]

Why does the output look so box like. It seems to me like it just doesn't capture all the data available in the dataframe. I'm sure it does though, so is this a formatting issue? How do you smooth this output line out so to remove sharp, edge like breaks?

Comment: I think `PMI.index` has only year, not date. Matplotlib appears to be considering this as a number and plotting the all values for a year on a single x-axis point. Convert the data to `pandas.datetime`

Comment: It only makes the plot line smooth if Date column is object type, but then it doesn't plot dates correctly. If I turn Date to pd.to_datetime, it still comes out box like. I know what you said should work but it is not.

Comment: Can't add much without the code and sample data. See if you can post this

Comment: I've added sample data and code.

Comment: This ran just fine... even extended it to 30 years with dummy data. Do a `df.info()` and check the Date column (pmi.Date). It should work if dtype is `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: This is correct. I've had corrupted data.